# Is it OK to ask a duplicated question when the original question doesn't have an appropriate answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I ran into this situation from time to time that the question that I wanted to ask has already been posted by someone several years ago. However, there are chances that the old posts may not make me satisfied due to:

- Things might have been changed dramatically during the years that what was considered as a good answer may be no longer suitable for now.
- The old question doesn't have any good answer at all. (There may be some answers, but the answers may not be good enough to give a complete insight of the problem)

But it seems that the freshness is a very important factor on the stackexchange websites for a question to be answered. So in this case, is it ok to re-post the same question again? Or are there any decent ways to draw attention for that question so that someone will take a look and hopefully give a better answer?

Comment: See also [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046) on meta.stackexchange.

Answer (score 10):

You can certainly try to ask it, and then see what happens, see how the community at large, but if you do, consider:

- Referencing the prior similar questions, showing what information they've given you, and also telling and showing as clearly as possible, why your question is not a complete duplicate.
- Posting a decent [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code post within your question as this can also be used to buttress your assertion that your question is more specific and unique
- Being extremely careful with questions that are asked *very* commonly and are felt to have canonical answers, such as the [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) as an example. We see so many of these types of questions on the site where the duplicate is in fact a true duplicate, should be closed, and the real issue is that the poster doesn't fully understand the answers to be found.